# I'm getting that orthogonal matrices don't (necessarily) have orthogonal rows/columns

Tags: orthogonal-matrices

As the title says, here's my "proof":

Let U be some orthogonal matrix:

Uᵀ = U⁻¹

∴ U Uᵀ = Uᵀ U = I

Considering the ijth element:

(U Uᵀ)ᵢⱼ = (Uᵀ U)ᵢⱼ = δᵢⱼ

∑UᵢₖUᵀₖⱼ = ∑UᵀᵢₖUₖⱼ = δᵢⱼ

∑UᵢₖUⱼₖ = ∑UₖᵢUₖⱼ = δᵢⱼ

The scalar product between two vectors is given by ⟨a,b⟩ = ∑aᵢ*bᵢ

We want to get ⟨Uⱼ,Uᵢ⟩ = ⟨Uⁱ,Uʲ⟩ = δᵢⱼ for orthonormality to be satisfied in the rows and columns of U.

But this isn't what I have, I'm only able to get the complex conjugate for when U is real (unitary) but not for the general case of orthogonal maps.

Comment: Your typesetting seems to not render, but I'll point out that for complex matrices, the correct notion of "orthogonal" (unitary) is $UU^\ast = I$, where $^\ast$ is *conjugate* transpose.

Comment: So for complex spaces orthogonal matrices are defined differently to real spaces? Would that not make the term unitary redundant as unitary is only applicable in complex spaces?

Comment: When talking about complex spaces, unitary is the notion used, yes. (This is essentially because the inner product is defined using conjugate as well.) I don't have any comment about the redundancy.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but my point about redundancy was that:

In real spaces, unitary = orthogonal because taking the conjugate of a real value returns itself.
In complex spaces, if we define orthogonal to be taking the hermitian conjugate instead of just the transpose then once again unitary = orthogonal.
So it seems as if we have two different terms to describe the same thing

Comment: "So for complex spaces orthogonal matrices are defined differently to real spaces?" You could see it that way. Or you could see it as defined in the exact same way, the complex conjugation is just invisible in the real case.

Comment: So if I had a matrix that had complex elements where it is equal to its transpose (not conjugate transpose), would that be unitary, orthogonal or neither?

Comment: Transposes the way you think you know them from real linear algebra have little consequence in complex linear algebra.